# Is there a permanent link to the sakila demo website?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, demo

Does anyone know of a permanent robust weblink to view the demo sakila database, which is hosted on phpmyadmin?

Yesterday the database was here, as per Google results:

https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/index.php?db=sakila

But this link now redirects me here with no sakila DB:

https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/index.php?reload=1

Today the website is under MariaDB instead of MySQL:

https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/db_structure.php?server=1&db=sakila

Does this database regularly move locations or is it incredibly coincidental that it has moved overnight? As a demo, perhaps anyone can change its location?

I have built an SQL course online and want students to use this sakila demo website. For this I need a reliable URL. Can anyone help me on what that would be, or at least help me understand why the DB has moved?

Thanks

Comment: "I have built an SQL course online and want students to use this sakila demo website to save them downloading and installing local servers etc. I need the sakila demo to be reliably available for them," Ideally you should make a MySQL user account with only SELECT rights then then nobody can DROP the database

Comment: Thanks Raymond. Do you mean I should host the sakila database myself and share read only login with students? Or is there a way of doing this with the demo account hosted at phpmyadmin? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

The Sakila Database is available here in PhpMyAdmin:

https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/index.php?db=sakila

You can download the Sakila database source [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-installation.html)

And find here a [Demo Sakila Database admin dashboard](https://www.phpcrudgenerator.com/admin/home) built with Bootstrap 4 and a CRUD Generator.